# put marker on a vector layer / map Qt-Qgis

Tags: qgis, c++, qt

I am designing a GUI using Qt and QGIS and showing maps (shapefiles - Vector layers) on the GUI. I want to put a marker on the vector layers when I click somewhere on the map. I could get coordinates when I click on the vector layer. I am using QLabel class for the marker. I am moving the marker according to coordinates. The logic and related part of the code is as following:

```
mpClickPoint = new QgsMapToolEmitPoint(mpMapCanvas);
connect(mpClickPoint, SIGNAL(canvasClicked(QgsPointXY,Qt::MouseButton)), this, SLOT(selectCoord(QgsPointXY)));

void MainWindow::selectCoord(QgsPointXY point)
{
QLabel *marker = new QLabel(mpMapCanvas);
marker->setPixmap(QPixmap(":/mapMarker.png"));
marker->move(point.x(), point.y());
marker->show();
}
```

The problem is, wherever I click on the map, the markers are put somewhere else and they are put so close to each other. As you can see in the image below, I clicked 10 times on different places and markers have been put in the area on the top left of the map. How can I put markers correctly? Or should I follow another way?

The Output is like follows:
[image]